# No item found for conditions Array locale.site.code

Tags: mysql, database, typo3

I'm setup Aimeos 19.10.5 on TYPO 9.5.3.

I followed all the steps, and I executed the update script of the Aimeos extension in the extension manager

but I get this error :

```
No item found for conditions: Array ( [locale.site.code] => default )
```

this is the log :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mydbname`.`#sql-6f7_52175438` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"): ALTER TABLE fe_users_address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_t3feuad_pid FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES fe_users (uid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with this solution :

1. I changed the fe_users table Engine, from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB`
2. run the SQL again :

`ALTER TABLE fe_users_address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_t3feuad_pid FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES fe_users (uid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`

3. executed again the update script of the Aimeos extension in the extension manager